# P12 files with iOS keychains

Tags: ios, security

Is there away to store a PKCS#12 file content as keychain item ? seems that keychain items can only be certificates, keys or passwords but not complete stores.

Alternatively is there away to store certificates, keys and their password in the iOS keychain in PKCS formate ?

Thanks
Jamil

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?